# can't change the data-mini attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes

I am using a textBox with the data-mini attribute set to true and a button to manipulate the input text box's attribute.

```
<input type="text" name="text1"  Value="Enter name" id="txt1" data-mini="true" ></text>

<input type="button" value="Update Attribute"  id="but1" onClick="$(this).UpAttr();"> </button>
```

Now What i want to change the **data-mini** to **false** on above button click. For this I have declared the method

```
$.fn.UpAttr=function()
    {
        $("#txt1").attr("data-mini","false");
        $("#txt1").attr("value","New Value");
         alert("The Button was clicked.");;
    }
```

But data-mini attribute is not set to false although the value attribute is updated on button click.
Can't find any solution for this !!
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `data()` function:

```
$.fn.UpAttr = function() {
    $("#txt1")
        .data('mini', false)
        .prop('value', 'New Value');
    alert('The Button was clicked.');
}
```

This is because jQuery keeps `data-*` attributes in an internal cache for performance reasons. Changing the attribute alone does not update that. If you check the page in any DOM inspector the HTML won't have changed, but jQuery's behaviour will.

Comment: This didn't worked frn... The layout for input text is still small in size !!

Comment: I would imagine that is caused by the plugin which is styling the input. You would probably need to remove then re-instantiate the plugin after changing the `data` attribute

Comment: Please guide me how to do so ??

Comment: You need to update your question to state what plugin you are using

Comment: I have only used following js file links
 <script src="js/popUP.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>    
</script>

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change than try this ,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hNnPz/)

```
document.getElementById('txt1').setAttribute('data-mini',false);
```

> The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery)

Comment: No frnd.. this didn't worked.. setAttribute is working for other attributes, dnt knw y its not updating data-mini.. !!

Comment: sorry their was typo check now

Comment: I have a text box in which data-mini is set to true by default. On button click I want to set the data-mini="false". But nothing works !!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41182/discussion-between-rajesh-kakawat-and-bhavna)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I updated the width of text box by modifying the style attribute. I solved it using:

```
<input type="text"  name="text1" id="txt1"  Value="Enter name" style="width:20%;" ></input>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Update Attribute"  id="but1" onClick="$(this).UpAttr();"> </input>
```

and updated the method as:

```
 $.fn.UpAttr=function()
    {

    $("#txt1").attr('style','width:80%;');
         alert("The Button was clicked.");
    }
```

Nd Plz check that any of the js or css files are not overriding it..

The value for the data-mini was updated by the previous code also but it was not reflected in the text box layout in the phonegap + android. May be some or the other css or js would be overriding it !! Thanx to @rajesh kakawat for exploring this. :)